# How can I find the cause of "null" characters in an http request response?

Tags: json, curl, airflow, httprequest

I have multiple http requests being made to multiple databases using cURL. Each cURL request is querying one table in a single database, getting all data between two timestamps.

These requests are being run by Airflow using multiple workers. **Each DAG has a task that makes requests for a single database**. There are multiple tasks inside each DAG and they are running sequentially, so if one fails Airflow will retry up to 3 times and it should not proceed to the next tasks.

The request tasks are Airflow BashOperator(s) that run multiple .sh files sequentially which contain the cURL commands. The responses are in JSON format and they are saved in individual .json files, one for each table.

One of the following tasks is sometimes failing. This task does some transformations on the data that was requested on the task before, reading the data stored in .json files. There is one .json file for each table of each database.

I looked into the logs and the .json files and there are **parsing errors** `parse error: premature EOF`. For a small table, the file is completely empty, so the error was on character 1. I thought there was some error with the cURL command that was not being raised. I was looking into the `--remove-on-error` option, in order to remove the output .json file if there is an error, and also `--retry` with `--retry-all-errors` in order to retry if an error occurs with cURL.

Before applying these changes, I looked into other similar errors on other DAGs and found out the same parsing error, but pointing to a character somewhere in the middle of that .json file. I looked into the file and what I see is a JSON structure that is filled with "null" characters somewhere in the middle. **Before and after that area, there is correct data shown.** About 25% of the total characters are "null". On the image below (text representation from Visual Studio Code), the "In" is still part of the data (incomplete word) but then start the "null" values.

[image: null characters]

I made the same request directly to the database on my local machine and I got a correctly structured JSON file. Comparing the two files, this "null" characters correspond to actual characters in the original data, since **the total number of characters is the same on
both files.**

On the case of the small tables, I thought some error was happening that was not being raised, but now I'm not sure what is happening, since apparently the cURL command continues.

Will both cases be fixed by the 3 parameters stated above? What exactly is happening here and why is the cURL command not failing? Or is this error coming from somewhere else?